# Ember.js View not properly passing context to router even

Tags: ember.js

I am having a bit of trouble with ember.js.

I have the following code which properly calls the event in the router to create the notebook. However, it will not pass the notebook context, it it undefined. I have been searching for hours to try and find a solution for this.

I found [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1692) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552417/emberjs-how-to-transition-to-a-router-from-a-controllers-action), which are helpful but I'm not completely sure I'm on the right track. Am I missing something?

Route

```
App.NotebooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
        App.Notebook.createRecord()
    events:
        create: (notebook) ->
            #persist notebook
```

Form

```
{{#with content}}
    <form {{action create content on="submit" }} >
        <div>
            {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Enter a title" valueBinding="title" }}
        </div>

        <div>
            {{view Ember.TextArea placeholder="Notes" valueBinding="description" }}
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Change `{{action create content on="submit" }}` to `{{action create this on="submit" }}`

> Why?

When you use the handlebars helper `{{#with}}`, the enclosed block will be rendered in the context of the specified variable. So after `{{#with content}}`, `this` is whatever `content` was and you can access properties like `title` and `description` directly instead of `content.title` and `content.description`